# Trouble with plotting (Beginner)

Tags: plotting, function-construction

So I need to "define and plot on an appropriate interval":

```
f[x_]=(3x^3-16x^2+28X-16)/(7x^3-9x^2+48x-20)
```

to see the behavior of the function.  The above function, however, doesn't work.  My Calculus professor, in his boundless wisdom, made a function where the x variables will simply cancel out.  I'm not sure what to do for a workaround, so I've been substituting `x==2`.

When I try to plot this function

```
Plot[f[2], {x, -20Pi, 20Pi}]
```

I receive a blank graph.  How do I make Mathematica draw the function? (or just a line, I'll settle for anything at this point.)

Later on I do have to "Plot the function and the horizontal line it approaches as `x->Infinity` on one graph" using the same function, so I'm hoping to eliminate the same potential problem for that as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You had one capital `X` in the function `f` (MMA is case sensitive), and when *defining* a function (i.e., with a construct like `f[x_]`) one needs to use `SetDelayed` (`:=`), not `Set` (`=`):

```
f[x_] := (3 x^3 - 16 x^2 + 28 x - 16)/(7 x^3 - 9 x^2 + 48 x - 20)
```

Then, you can plot the function by calling it with `f[x]` (without the underscript `_` anymore):

```
plot = Plot[f[x], {x, -20 Pi, 20 Pi}, PlotRange -> {All, {-1, 1}}, Frame -> True]
```

[image]

To find the limit of `f[x]` in infinity:

```
limit = Limit[f[x], x -> Infinity]
```

> 3/7

We can now either plot two functions on the same plot:

```
Plot[{f[x], limit}, {x, -20 Pi, 20 Pi}, PlotRange -> {All, {-1, 1}}, 
 Frame -> True, PlotStyle -> {Automatic, Red}]
```

[image]

or make two plots and `Show` them together:

```
plot2 = Plot[limit, {x, -20 Pi, 20 Pi}, PlotRange -> {All, {-1, 1}}, 
  Frame -> True, PlotStyle -> Red]

Show[plot, plot2]
```

[image]

Finally, we can also find the location of the vertical asymptote: it's where the denominator equals to zero:

```
a = Solve[Denominator[f[x]] == 0, x][[1]]
```

[image]

or approximately

```
N[a]
```

> {x -> 0.440591}

The other two roots are complex.

The function `f[x]` has its zeros where its numerator is equal to zero:

```
Solve[Numerator[f[x]] == 0, x]
```

> {{x -> 4/3}, {x -> 2}, {x -> 2}}

```
Plot[f[x], {x, 1, 2.5}, Frame -> True, FrameLabel -> {"x", "f(x)"}, 
 Epilog -> {PointSize[Large], Red, Point[{{4/3, 0}, {2, 0}}]}]
```

[image]

Comment: "one needs to use SetDelayed (:=), not Set (=)", not 100% true. For a newbie, it is a simple way to distinguish the two, but the answer is more [subtle](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/18487/52).

Comment: @rcollyer Yes, I was thinking whether to elaborate more on it (to make it 100% correct) or not (to not make beginners confused); but I think that your comment and the provided link are enough here.

Comment: Running a [query for "Set SetDelayed"](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/search?q=Set+SetDelayed) returns a whole panoply of even more subtleties then the pitfall answer. Stuff I've never thought of before. But, a new user should beware: here be dragons.

Answer (score 3):

There are some mistakes in what you are doing:

1. The function is supposted to be (note that `Mathematica` is case sensitive, you have capital `X`, also there is a difference between `:=` and `=`, I suggest reading help): `f[x_] := (3 x^3 - 16 x^2 + 28 x - 16)/(7 x^3 - 9 x^2 + 48 x - 20);`
2. Your plot is just plotting a constant that is a line, not a blank graph...Try: `Plot[f[x], {x, -20 Pi, 20 Pi}]`